# Get displaylevels/zoom level javascript API

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online-basemaps

Is there any way using JavaScript API to get the current "displayLevels" of the basemap or "basemap zoom level" or "basemap scale" of the map and if it was more/less than certain number I change the Layer to another layer?

```
function(
        Map,
        FeatureLayer
        ){

map = new Map("map", {
           basemap: "topo",
           center: [-85.416, 49.781],
           zoom : 5,
           logo: false});
if (map zoom level == ***) {

 layer1 = new FeatureLayer(
                "http://testServer/arcgis/rest/services/test/MapServer/0", {
                        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND
                        });

        map.addLayer(layer1);
}

else {
layer2 = new FeatureLayer(
                "http://testServer/arcgis/rest/services/test/MapServer/1", {
                        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND
                        });

        map.addLayer(layer2);

}
```

Comment: how to get current zoom level in arcgis 4.0 map javascript..
map.getLevel() is not a method arcGis 4.0 API MAP Class...please tell me how to get current zoom level in arcGis 4.0 Map

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/95629)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Map has the property [getLevel](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#getlevel) which you can use to find the zoom level.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.7/js/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        background-color: #FFF;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.7/"></script>
  <script>
    var map;

    require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "topo",
          center: [-122.45,37.75], // long, lat
          zoom: 13,
          sliderStyle: "small"
        });

        map.on("extent-change", function(){console.log(map.getLevel());})
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```